# Fatal error when trying to install yaireo/Tagify

Tags: github, npm, npm-install

I have a hosted webhotel from UnoEuro and via SSH I am trying to install Tagify script. https://github.com/yairEO/tagify

I am trying to install

```
npm i @yaireo/tagify --save
```

I get this error:

```
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:yaireo/tagify Initialized empty Git repository in /var/www/maxie.dk/.npm/_git-remotes/git-github-com-yaireo-tagify-8fe20c9e/
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:yaireo/tagify 
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:yaireo/tagify Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! git clone git@github.com:yaireo/tagify fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install yaireo/tagify
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, stat 'yaireo/tagify'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-954.3.5.lve1.4.63.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "@yaireo/tagify"
npm ERR! cwd /var/www/maxie.dk/public_html/labels
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.48
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.6
npm ERR! path yaireo/tagify
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /var/www/maxie.dk/public_html/labels/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

I am not so familiar with npm and SSH so I am not sure what the error means. Can anyone help me in letting me know what to try/do?

I see the error also contained "Permission denied (PublicKey) but I believe to have tried both with private and public keys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try [this](https://help.github.com/en/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey).Hope this helpful for you.

Comment: How can an `npm i` command trigger a `git clone` command? are you sure you are running only `npm i ...` and nothing else?